# Since there is SQL injection, why does SQL Databases still use script language

Tags: sql, security, web, sql-injection

I mean,if we use some binary-based language,we prevent the SQL injection throughy don't we?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary-based"?  You mean strongly typed?

Comment: Surely if an attacker can inject arbitrary text, they can in principle inject any other byte string?

Comment: Might just as well ask why do we still use SMTP for e-mail given that there is no sender verification. It's just how it is, and changing it now is not going to happen. You can use always use an ORM layer like Entity Framework in C# if you'd like a strongly typed language

Comment: Ideas don't need to have a reason **not** to exist. The default state of things is non-existence. If you have an idea, go make it. Or describe it, advocate for it, convince others to make it. As is, I have no idea what it is you're advocating for, nor why it would be better than SQL. You must describe your SQL replacement idea if we are to discuss it.

Comment: @D Stanley   I mean that you can't execute a string. you only threat the data in code segmentt execuable

Comment: It's quite hard to express the sets of queries and joins a DBMS might want to do in something other than a language—even some of the NoSQLs have invented their own query languages (and sadly often re-invented query injection in the process). Even if you did you would face the problem of compatibility: it has taken us ages to get to the point where there's even a basic level of cross-DBMS SQL standards compliance and a new standard would be hard to make stick.

Comment: To get to the goal of separating code from data to defeat SQL injection I think the simpler route would be simply to optionally disallow literals in queries, requiring parameterisation be used for all values. You could still get in trouble with queries whose structure is constucted from data, but that's a much less common mistake than injection into literals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The language that's being used is not the problem.

The problem is building SQL statements using data from untrusted sources.

It doesn't matter if it's PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
```

or if it's in C:

```
sprintf( sql, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '%s'", id );
```

In both cases, if the `id` or `$id` variable is untrusted input from an outside data source, the SQL being built is tainted.  In either case, if an attacker passes in an `id` of `'; drop table users;`, then you're building:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ''; drop table users;
```

The answer to avoiding SQL injection is: **do not build SQL statements using outside data**.

Comment: Alternatively, **use parameterized queries**, which most languages have access to (PHP mysqli or PDO, for example)

Comment: "Use parametrized queries" is exactly what I'm referring to when I say "do not build SQL statements using outside data".  It's not an alternative; it's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: It's not the source of the data that's the problem, building statements even using ‘trusted’ internal data is the wrong thing. Keeping data and control code separate is what's important.